# Wrong post id for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, revolution-slider

I use a Revolution slider on my page and I am using `meta based` content depending on post-id.
The problem is that the Revolution slider not take `custom post` type `post id` but current `page id`.
Is there way to fix it?
This is what I use in the Revolution slider:

```
[acf field="moto_name" post_id="{{id}}"]
```

This is what I use to call my custom post types in my custom wordpress page:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'moto',
    'meta_key'      => 'moto_name',
    'meta_value'    => $name
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

What can I do, to make revslider use custom `post type ID` instead of `page id` ?

Comment: _"This is what I use in the Revolution slider"_ - meaning what, exactly - is this content you insert via the editor, or does this get evaluated as part of your template (using `do_shortcode`)?